Настроить в google поиск выдачу только главной(первой, root, домен) страницы каждого сайта по моему запросу, мне надо что-бы сайты не дубрировались
В общем, могу использовать парсер или библиотеку для поиска, но желательно делать обычным google. К сожалению я не сообразил и не нашёл ответ на этот вопрос. Сам помогаю в настройке  rtmp и openWRT uci, dns и т.д - хоть убейте, не могу найти ответ на эту задачу.

когда-то был параметр "inurl" предлагаю в него поставить index OR home OR welcome но это не даст 100% результат будут траблы типа главная форума сайта, главная блога сайта итп

Да, спасибо, полагаю если бы был REGEX, можно было-бы сделать что-то вроде https:/*/$ или например параметр depth = 1 ,       Всё же наверное стоит опросить google программой, есть способ сделать это в соответствии с политикой пользования или api? а уже результаты отсортировать
